# Painfully slow Postgres query using WHERE on many adjacent rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, nlp, query-performance, part-of-speech

I have the following psql table. It has roughly 2 billion rows in total.

```
 id  word      lemma     pos              textid  source     
 1  Stuffing   stuff      vvg             190568  AN         
 2  her        her        appge           190568  AN         
 3  key        key        nn1             190568  AN         
 4  into       into       ii              190568  AN         
 5  the        the        at              190568  AN         
 6  lock       lock       nn1             190568  AN         
 7  she        she        appge           190568  AN         
 8  pushed     push       vvd             190568  AN         
 9  her        her        appge           190568  AN         
10  way        way        nn1             190568  AN         
11  into       into       ii              190568  AN         
12  the        the        appge           190568  AN         
13  house      house      nn1             190568  AN         
14  .                     .               190568  AN         
15  She        she        appge           190568  AN         
16  had        have       vhd             190568  AN         
17  also       also       rr              190568  AN         
18  cajoled    cajole     vvd             190568  AN         
19  her        her        appge           190568  AN         
20  way        way        nn1             190568  AN         
21  into       into       ii              190568  AN         
22  the        the        at              190568  AN         
23  home       home       nn1             190568  AN         
24  .                     .               190568  AN         
..  ...        ...        ..              ...     ..
```

I would like to create the following table, which shows all "way"-constructions with the words side-by-side and some data from the columns "source", "lemma" and "pos".

```
source     word   word       word       lemma      pos        word       word     word       word       word       lemma      pos        word       word       
AN         lock   she        pushed     push       vvd        her        way      into       the        house      house      nn1        .          she
AN         had    also       cajoled    cajole     vvd        her        way      into       the        home       home       nn1        .          A          
AN         tried  to         force      force      vvi        her        way      into       the        palace     palace     nn1        ,          officials
```

Here you can see the code I use:

```
copy(
SELECT   c1.source, c1.word,  c2.word, c3.word,  c4.word, c4.lemma, c4.pos, c5.word, c6.word, c7.word, c8.word, c9.word, c9.lemma, c9.pos, c10.word, c11.word

FROM 

orderedflatcorpus AS c1, orderedflatcorpus AS c2, orderedflatcorpus AS c3, orderedflatcorpus AS c4, orderedflatcorpus AS c5, orderedflatcorpus AS c6, orderedflatcorpus AS c7, orderedflatcorpus AS c8, orderedflatcorpus AS c9, orderedflatcorpus AS c10, orderedflatcorpus AS c11

WHERE

c1.word LIKE '%' AND
c2.word LIKE '%' AND
c3.word LIKE '%' AND
c4.pos LIKE 'v%' AND
c5.pos = 'appge' AND
c6.lemma = 'way' AND
c7.pos LIKE 'i%' AND
c8.word = 'the' AND
c9.pos LIKE 'n%' AND
c10.word LIKE '%' AND
c11.word LIKE '%' 

AND 

c1.id + 1 = c2.id AND c1.id + 2 = c3.id AND c1.id + 3 = c4.id AND c1.id + 4 = c5.id AND c1.id + 5 = c6.id AND c1.id + 6 = c7.id AND c1.id + 7 = c8.id AND c1.id + 8 = c9.id AND c1.id + 9 = c10.id AND c1.id + 10 = c11.id

ORDER BY c1.id
)
TO 
'/home/postgres/Results/OUTPUT.csv'
DELIMITER E'\t'
csv header;
```

The query takes almost 9 hours to execute for the two billion rows (the result has about 19,000 rows).

What could I do to improve performance?

The word, pos and lemma columns already have btree indices.

Should I stick to my code and simply use a more powerful server with more cores/a faster CPU and more RAM (mine has only 8 GBs of RAM, a mere 2 cores and 2.8 GHz) ? Or would you recommend a different, more efficient SQL query?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the intention of `c1.word LIKE '%'`? This expression is always true.

Comment: I just want to make sure the word is extracted; it doesn’t matter which word it is. LIKE ‘%’ is meant as a wildcard. Would you suggest a different approach?

Comment: `'%'` matches the blank string too. Perhaps you mean `'_%'` (at least one character)?

Comment: @Bohemian: actually it's not true for `null` values. But it's equivalent to `c1.word is not null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using modern join syntax, which may well fix the problem:

```
SELECT
  c1.source, c1.word,  c2.word, c3.word,  c4.word, c4.lemma, c4.pos, c5.word, c6.word, c7.word, c8.word, c9.word, c9.lemma, c9.pos, c10.word, c11.word
FROM orderedflatcorpus AS c1
JOIN orderedflatcorpus AS c2 ON c1.id + 1 = c2.id
JOIN orderedflatcorpus AS c3 ON c1.id + 2 = c3.id 
JOIN orderedflatcorpus AS c4 ON c1.id + 3 = c4.id
JOIN orderedflatcorpus AS c5 ON c1.id + 4 = c5.id
JOIN orderedflatcorpus AS c6 ON c1.id + 5 = c6.id
JOIN orderedflatcorpus AS c7 ON c1.id + 6 = c7.id
JOIN orderedflatcorpus AS c8 ON c1.id + 7 = c8.id
JOIN orderedflatcorpus AS c9 ON c1.id + 8 = c9.id
JOIN orderedflatcorpus AS c10 ON c1.id + 9 = c10.id
JOIN orderedflatcorpus AS c11 ON c1.id + 10 = c11.id
WHERE c4.pos LIKE 'v%'
AND c5.pos = 'appge'
AND c6.lemma = 'way'
AND c7.pos LIKE 'i%'
AND c8.word = 'the'
AND c9.pos LIKE 'n%'
```

Notes:

- redundant `LIKE`s removed
- `ORDER BY` removed, because it's very expensive. CSV (like table rows) don't need ordering to be valid. If you absolutely need ordering, use command line tools to order it after the execution of the query.

Comment: Thanks so much, this search expression takes five hours instead of nine. Excellent job.

Comment: Try my (first) solution. (it will probably take only a fraction of that) The second one could be ten times faster, but it will take some time to get the DDL corrected)

Comment: I now use this approach. It is very useful, but am slightly worried since I found out that I get fewer and fewer results, the more columns I add (i.e. the more joins I make). The code shown above gives 18706 lines, if I go from 11 to 14 joins (c1–c14, same syntax as above, exactly the same conditions), I get 18674, if it's 21 words (c1–c21), I only get 18555 lines. I have looked at the lines left out, but I cannot see any systematic reason. Does anyone have an idea what this might be due to? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Step1:use a window function to obtain *adjacent* records, avoiding the painful self-join (12 tables is very close to the limit where **geqo** takes over):

---

```
copy(
WITH stuff AS (
    SELECT   c1.id , c1.source, c1.word
    , LEAD ( c1.word, 1) OVER (www) AS c2w
    , LEAD (c1.word, 2) OVER (www) AS c3w
    , LEAD ( c1.word, 3) OVER (www) AS c4w
    , LEAD (c1.lemma, 3) OVER (www) AS c4l
    , LEAD (c1.pos, 3) OVER (www) AS c4p
    , LEAD (c1.pos, 4) OVER (www) AS c5p
    , LEAD (c1.word, 4) OVER (www) AS c5w
    , LEAD (c1.word, 5) OVER (www) AS c6w
    , LEAD (c1.lemma, 5) OVER (www) AS c6l
    , LEAD (c1.word, 6) OVER (www) AS c7w
    , LEAD (c1.pos, 6) OVER (www) AS c7p
    , LEAD (c1.word, 7) OVER (www) AS c8w
    , LEAD (c1.word, 8) OVER (www) AS c9w
    , LEAD (c1.lemma, 8) OVER (www) AS c9l
    , LEAD (c1.pos, 8) OVER (www) AS c9p
    , LEAD (c1.word, 9) OVER (www) AS c10w
    , LEAD (c1.word, 10) OVER (www) AS c11w
    FROM orderedflatcorpus AS c1
    WINDOW www AS (ORDER BY id)
    )
SELECT id ,  source, word
    , c2w
    , c3w
    , c4w
    , c4l
    , c4p
    , c5w
    , c6w
    , c7w
    , c8w
    , c9w
    , c9l
    , c9p
    , c10w
    , c11w
FROM stuff
WHERE 1=1
AND c4p LIKE 'v%'
AND c5p = 'appge'
AND c6l = 'way'
AND c7p LIKE 'i%'
AND c8w = 'the'
AND c9p LIKE 'n%'
ORDER BY id
)
-- TO '/home/postgres/Results/OUTPUT.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' csv header;
TO '/tmp/OUTPUT2.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' csv header;
```

---

Step 2: [data model] The {word,lemma, pos} columns appear to be a low-cardinality group, you could squeeze them out into a separate token/lemma/pos-table:

---

```
    -- An index to speedup the unique extraction and final update
    -- (the index will be dropped automatically
    -- once the columns are dropped)
    CREATE INDEX ON tmp.orderedflatcorpus (word, lemma, pos );

    ANALYZE tmp.orderedflatcorpus;
    -- table containing the "squeezed out" domain
    CREATE TABLE tmp.words AS
     SELECT DISTINCT  word, lemma, pos
     FROM tmp.orderedflatcorpus
            ;
    ALTER TABLE tmp.words
     ADD COLUMN id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;

    ALTER TABLE tmp.words
     ADD UNIQUE (word , lemma, pos );

    -- The original table needs an FK "link" to the new table
    ALTER TABLE tmp.orderedflatcorpus
      ADD column words_id INTEGER -- NOT NULL
      REFERENCES tmp.words(id)
      ;
    -- FK constraints are helped a lot by a supportive index.
    CREATE INDEX orderedflatcorpus_words_id_fk ON tmp.orderedflatcorpus (words_id)
     ;
    ANALYZE tmp.orderedflatcorpus;
    ANALYZE tmp.words;
    -- Initialize the FK column in the original table.
    --  we need NOT DISTINCT FROM here, since the joined
    --  columns could contain NULLs , which MUST compare equal.
    -- ------------------------------------------------------
    UPDATE tmp.orderedflatcorpus dst
       SET  words_id = src.id
      FROM tmp.words src
     WHERE src.word IS NOT DISTINCT FROM dst.word
       AND dst.lemma IS NOT DISTINCT FROM src.lemma
       AND dst.pos IS NOT DISTINCT FROM src.pos
            ;
    ALTER TABLE tmp.orderedflatcorpus
     DROP column word
     , DROP column lemma
     , DROP column pos
            ;
```

---

And the new query, with a JOIN to the words-table:

---

```
copy(
WITH stuff AS (
    SELECT   c1.id , c1.source, w.word
    , LEAD ( w.word, 1) OVER (www) AS c2w
    , LEAD (w.word, 2) OVER (www) AS c3w
    , LEAD ( w.word, 3) OVER (www) AS c4w
    , LEAD (w.lemma, 3) OVER (www) AS c4l
    , LEAD (w.pos, 3) OVER (www) AS c4p
    , LEAD (w.pos, 4) OVER (www) AS c5p
    , LEAD (w.word, 4) OVER (www) AS c5w
    , LEAD (w.word, 5) OVER (www) AS c6w
    , LEAD (w.lemma, 5) OVER (www) AS c6l
    , LEAD (w.word, 6) OVER (www) AS c7w
    , LEAD (w.pos, 6) OVER (www) AS c7p
    , LEAD (w.word, 7) OVER (www) AS c8w
    , LEAD (w.word, 8) OVER (www) AS c9w
    , LEAD (w.lemma, 8) OVER (www) AS c9l
    , LEAD (w.pos, 8) OVER (www) AS c9p
    , LEAD (w.word, 9) OVER (www) AS c10w
    , LEAD (w.word, 10) OVER (www) AS c11w
    FROM orderedflatcorpus AS c1
    JOIN words w ON w.id=c1.words_id
    WINDOW www AS (ORDER BY c1.id)
    )
SELECT id ,  source, word
    , c2w , c3w
    , c4w , c4l , c4p
    , c5w
    , c6w
    , c7w
    , c8w
    , c9w , c9l , c9p
    , c10w
    , c11w
FROM stuff
WHERE 1=1
AND c4p LIKE 'v%'
AND c5p = 'appge'
AND c6l = 'way'
AND c7p LIKE 'i%'
AND c8w = 'the'
AND c9p LIKE 'n%'
ORDER BY id
)
-- TO '/home/postgres/Results/OUTPUT.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' csv header;
TO '/tmp/OUTPUT3.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' csv header;
```

---

Note: I get two lines in the output, because I relaxed the conditions a bit too much ...

---

**Update** :the first query, avoiding the CTE

---

```
copy(
SELECT id ,  source, word
        , c2w
        , c3w
        , c4w
        , c4l
        , c4p
        , c5w
        , c6w
        , c7w
        , c8w
        , c9w
        , c9l
        , c9p
        , c10w
        , c11w
FROM (
        SELECT   c1.id , c1.source, c1.word
        , LEAD ( c1.word, 1) OVER (www) AS c2w
        , LEAD (c1.word, 2) OVER (www) AS c3w
        , LEAD ( c1.word, 3) OVER (www) AS c4w
        , LEAD (c1.lemma, 3) OVER (www) AS c4l
        , LEAD (c1.pos, 3) OVER (www) AS c4p
        , LEAD (c1.pos, 4) OVER (www) AS c5p
        , LEAD (c1.word, 4) OVER (www) AS c5w
        , LEAD (c1.word, 5) OVER (www) AS c6w
        , LEAD (c1.lemma, 5) OVER (www) AS c6l
        , LEAD (c1.word, 6) OVER (www) AS c7w
        , LEAD (c1.pos, 6) OVER (www) AS c7p
        , LEAD (c1.word, 7) OVER (www) AS c8w
        , LEAD (c1.word, 8) OVER (www) AS c9w
        , LEAD (c1.lemma, 8) OVER (www) AS c9l
        , LEAD (c1.pos, 8) OVER (www) AS c9p
        , LEAD (c1.word, 9) OVER (www) AS c10w
        , LEAD (c1.word, 10) OVER (www) AS c11w
        FROM orderedflatcorpus AS c1
        WINDOW www AS (ORDER BY id)
        ) stuff
WHERE 1=1
AND c4p LIKE 'v%'
AND c5p = 'appge'
AND c6l = 'way'
AND c7p LIKE 'i%'
AND c8w = 'the'
AND c9p LIKE 'n%'
ORDER BY id
)
-- TO '/home/postgres/Results/OUTPUT.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' csv header;
TO '/tmp/OUTPUT2a.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' csv header;
```

---

[a similar transformation could be performed on the second query]

---

**UPDATE2** The subquery version for the two table variant.

---

```
-- copy(
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT c1i, c1s, c1w
        , c2w , c3w
        , c4w , c4l , c4p
        , c5w
        , c6w
        , c7w
        , c8w
        , c9w , c9l , c9p
        , c10w
        , c11w
FROM (
        SELECT c1.id AS c1i
        , c1.source AS c1s
        , w1.word AS c1w
        , LEAD (w1.word, 1) OVER www AS c2w
        , LEAD (w1.word, 2) OVER www AS c3w
        , LEAD (w1.word, 3) OVER www AS c4w
        , LEAD (w1.lemma, 3) OVER www AS c4l
        , LEAD (w1.pos, 3) OVER www AS c4p
        , LEAD (w1.pos, 4) OVER www AS c5p
        , LEAD (w1.word, 4) OVER www AS c5w
        , LEAD (w1.word, 5) OVER www AS c6w
        , LEAD (w1.lemma, 5) OVER www AS c6l
        , LEAD (w1.word, 6) OVER www AS c7w
        , LEAD (w1.pos, 6) OVER www AS c7p
        , LEAD (w1.word, 7) OVER www AS c8w
        , LEAD (w1.word, 8) OVER www AS c9w
        , LEAD (w1.lemma, 8) OVER www AS c9l
        , LEAD (w1.pos, 8) OVER www AS c9p
        , LEAD (w1.word, 9) OVER www AS c10w
        , LEAD (w1.word, 10) OVER www AS c11w
        FROM orderedflatcorpus c1
        JOIN words w1 ON w1.id=c1.words_id
        WHERE 1=1
/*      These *could* to prune out unmatched items, but I could not get it to work ...
        AND EXISTS (SELECT *FROM orderedflatcorpus c4 JOIN words w4 ON w4.id=c4.words_id
                WHERE c4.id = 3+c1.id -- AND w4.pos LIKE 'v%'
                )  -- OMG
        AND EXISTS (SELECT *FROM orderedflatcorpus c5 JOIN words w5 ON w5.id=c5.words_id
                WHERE c5.id = 4+c1.id -- AND w5.pos = 'appge'
                ) -- OMG
        AND EXISTS (SELECT *FROM orderedflatcorpus c7 JOIN words w7 ON w7.id=c7.words_id
                WHERE c7.id = 6+c1.id -- AND w7.pos LIKE 'i%'
                ) -- OMG
        AND EXISTS (SELECT *FROM orderedflatcorpus c9 JOIN words w9 ON w9.id=c9.words_id
                WHERE c9.id = 8+c1.id -- AND w9.pos LIKE 'n%'
                ) -- OMG
        AND EXISTS (SELECT *FROM orderedflatcorpus c8 JOIN words w8 ON w8.id=c8.words_id
                WHERE c8.id = 7+c1.id -- AND w8.word = 'the'
                )  -- OMG
*/
         WINDOW www AS (ORDER BY c1.id ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 10 FOLLOWING)
        ) stuff
WHERE 1=1
AND c4p LIKE 'v%'
AND c5p = 'appge'
AND c6l = 'way'
AND c7p LIKE 'i%'
AND c8w = 'the'
AND c9p LIKE 'n%'
ORDER BY c1i
        ;
   -- )
-- TO '/home/postgres/Results/OUTPUT.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' csv header;
-- TO '/tmp/OUTPUT3b.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' csv header;
```

Comment: Dear wildplasser, thanks so much for your solutions, I really like them because they are so elegant. Unfortunately, your step 1 took almost nine hours – which is certainly not due to your code but to my slow server. I believe that the bottleneck is the ORDER statement in your window definition – ordering 2 billion rows takes ages.

Comment: No, it is not the `order by id` (assuming id is the PK) , IMHO  it is the materialize on the CTE taking place(check the plan) .  Replacing the CTE by a subselect *could* help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to reformat your query just a bit and see what we can see. The first thing to do is to change it over to use ANSI-style joins so we can clearly see what the relationships are:

```
SELECT c1.source, c1.word,  c2.word, c3.word, c4.word,
       c4.lemma, c4.pos, c5.word, c6.word, c7.word,
       c8.word, c9.word, c9.lemma, c9.pos, c10.word, c11.word
  FROM orderedflatcorpus c1
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c2
    ON c2.ID = c1.ID + 1 AND
       c2.WORD LIKE '%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c3
    ON c3.ID = c1.ID + 2 AND
       c3.WORD LIKE '%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c4
    ON c4.ID = c1.ID + 3 AND
       c4.pos LIKE 'v%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c5
    ON c5.ID = c1.ID + 4 AND
       c5.pos = 'appge'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c6
    ON c6.ID = c1.ID + 5 AND
       c6.lemma = 'way'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c7
    ON c7.ID = c1.ID + 6 AND
       c7.pos LIKE 'i%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c8
    ON c8.ID = c1.ID + 7 AND
       c8.word = 'the'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c9
    ON c9.ID = c1.ID + 8 AND
       c9.pos LIKE 'n%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c10
    ON c10.ID = c1.ID + 9 AND
       c10.WORD LIKE '%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c11
    ON c11.ID = c1.ID + 10 AND
       c11.WORD LIKE '%'
WHERE c1.WORD LIKE '%'
ORDER BY c1.id
```

OK, first off - all those LIKE's are killing this query. Let's eliminate them where we can. I'm going to assume here that WORD can't be NULL in ORDEREDFLATCORPUS, and thus all the `IS LIKE '%'` conditions can be eliminated:

```
SELECT c1.source, c1.word,  c2.word, c3.word, c4.word,
       c4.lemma, c4.pos, c5.word, c6.word, c7.word,
       c8.word, c9.word, c9.lemma, c9.pos, c10.word, c11.word
  FROM orderedflatcorpus c1
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c2
    ON c2.ID = c1.ID + 1
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c3
    ON c3.ID = c1.ID + 2
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c4
    ON c4.ID = c1.ID + 3 AND
       c4.pos LIKE 'v%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c5
    ON c5.ID = c1.ID + 4 AND
       c5.pos = 'appge'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c6
    ON c6.ID = c1.ID + 5 AND
       c6.lemma = 'way'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c7
    ON c7.ID = c1.ID + 6 AND
       c7.pos LIKE 'i%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c8
    ON c8.ID = c1.ID + 7 AND
       c8.word = 'the'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c9
    ON c9.ID = c1.ID + 8 AND
       c9.pos LIKE 'n%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c10
    ON c10.ID = c1.ID + 9
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c11
    ON c11.ID = c1.ID + 10
ORDER BY c1.id
```

If WORD can be NULL, then you might need to use:

```
SELECT c1.source, c1.word,  c2.word, c3.word, c4.word,
       c4.lemma, c4.pos, c5.word, c6.word, c7.word,
       c8.word, c9.word, c9.lemma, c9.pos, c10.word, c11.word
  FROM orderedflatcorpus c1
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c2
    ON c2.ID = c1.ID + 1 AND
       c2.WORD IS NOT NULL
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c3
    ON c3.ID = c1.ID + 2 AND
       c3.WORD IS NOT NULL
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c4
    ON c4.ID = c1.ID + 3 AND
       c4.pos LIKE 'v%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c5
    ON c5.ID = c1.ID + 4 AND
       c5.pos = 'appge'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c6
    ON c6.ID = c1.ID + 5 AND
       c6.lemma = 'way'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c7
    ON c7.ID = c1.ID + 6 AND
       c7.pos LIKE 'i%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c8
    ON c8.ID = c1.ID + 7 AND
       c8.word = 'the'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c9
    ON c9.ID = c1.ID + 8 AND
       c9.pos LIKE 'n%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c10
    ON c10.ID = c1.ID + 9 AND
       c10.WORD IS NOT NULL
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c11
    ON c11.ID = c1.ID + 10 AND
       c11.WORD IS NOT NULL
WHERE c1.WORD IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY c1.id
```

Next - this query needs to do as much filtering as it can as early as it possibly can. The database query optimizer *may* be able to figure this out, but let's give it some help by putting the equijoins first in the join list, and then adjusting the ID calculations to reflect the information we're getting first:

```
SELECT c1.source, c1.word,  c2.word, c3.word, c4.word,
       c4.lemma, c4.pos, c5.word, c6.word, c7.word,
       c8.word, c9.word, c9.lemma, c9.pos, c10.word, c11.word
  FROM DUAL
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c5
    ON c5.pos = 'appge'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c6
    ON c6.ID = c5.ID + 1 AND
       c6.lemma = 'way'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c8
    ON c8.ID = c5.ID + 3 AND
       c8.word = 'the'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c1
    ON c1.ID = c5.ID - 4 AND
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c2
    ON c2.ID = c5.ID - 3
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c3
    ON c3.ID = c5.ID - 2
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c4
    ON c4.ID = c5.ID - 1 AND
       c4.pos LIKE 'v%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c7
    ON c7.ID = c5.ID + 2 AND
       c7.pos LIKE 'i%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c9
    ON c9.ID = c5.ID + 4 AND
       c9.pos LIKE 'n%'
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c10
    ON c10.ID = c5.ID + 5
  INNER JOIN orderedflatcorpus c11
    ON c11.ID = c5.ID + 6
ORDER BY c1.id
```

Next we need to consider what indexes would be most useful. I think the following indexes would be worth having:

```
(ID)
(ID, WORD)
(ID, LEMMA)
(ID, POS)
```

Put those indexes on, run this query, and see if it helps. Also, check the ID calculations - I *think* I got them right but... :-)

Best of luck.